# Click on image to show next image in array - vue blogpost with modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'd like to add a function to my blogposts where I can click an image and it'll automatically jump to the next image AND text.

I have made a simplistic version without the blog's structure, that works.
Like so: https://i.gyazo.com/81c5baa0348518fd3327c303dac07dfc.mp4

But when I try to modify it to my blog's (Vue) structure, it won't work anymore, what am I doing wrong? I even tried some code I found on stack.

The commented out code is my own original code.

Follow-up question, how would I loop through text? Same way? At first glance I can't think of how.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Test pics</h1>
  <div> 
    <!--<img v-bind:src="images[hovered]" v-on:click="changePicture()" width="100px">-->
    <img v-if="image" :key="image" @click="changePicture" class="image" :src="image" alt="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue/Js

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
    image:null,
    posts: [
      {
        id:1,
        hovered: 0,
        images: ['https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=1','https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=2','https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=3'],
        text: ['text=1','text=2','text=3']
      },
      {
        id:2,
        hovered: 0,
        images: ['https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff','https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00f/fff','https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fbh/fff'],
        text: ['dummy=1','dummy=2','dummy=3']
      }]
  };
  },
  mounted(){
    this.changePicture();
  },
  methods: {
    changePicture() {
      this.post.hovered = this.post.images[this.post.hovered];
      this.post.hovered = (this.post.hovered + 1) % this.post.images.length;

      /*this.post.hovered = (++this.post.hovered)%(this.post.images.length);
      console.log(this.post.hovered+1);*/
    }
  }
})
```

EDIT:

The code that works:
https://codepen.io/TCGPlaza/collab/QWxJXbp/01272374f7f79eb5efdd4bfcb2bb93f3

I want the working code to basically be replicated for multiple separate posts. Say I make a new post and I add 6 images, then all I have to do is click the image 6 times to make it back to the first image. Other posts might only have 2 images etc...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working exactly and what error you are seeing? Also, can you post the code of the example in an jsfiddle or codesandbox?

Comment: Right of the bat, it looks like you have a property 'posts' (plural) but then are trying to access a property 'post' (singular).

Comment: Edited the post. I know about the post and posts, I tried a couple of iterations and spelling. Right now it shows the alt, whereas before it didn't even show "test pics"(title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly try like following snippet:

First in mounted hook fill images array with objects that contains image, text and index number of image for every element of `posts.images` array)

In method `changePicture` pass index, check if nr is lower then images array length, then if it is increment it or if is not start from index 0.

Finally update your images array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      images:[],
      posts: [{id:1, hovered: 0, images: ['https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=1','https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=2','https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=3','https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=4','https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=5'], text: ['text=1','text=2','text=3','text=4','text=5']}, {id:2, hovered: 0, images: ['https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff','https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00f/fff','https://dummyimage.com/600x400/fbh/fff'], text: ['dummy=1','dummy=2','dummy=3']}]
    };
  },
  mounted(){
    this.posts.forEach(p => this.images.push({img: p.images[0], text: p.text[0], nr: 0}));
  },
  methods: {
    changePicture(idx) {
      let nr = this.images[idx].nr
      if (nr + 1 < this.posts[idx].images.length) {
        nr++ 
      } else {
        nr = 0
      }
      this.images[idx].img = this.posts[idx].images[nr]
      this.images[idx].text = this.posts[idx].text[nr]
      this.images[idx].nr = nr
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Test pics</h1>
  <div v-for="(post, idx) in posts" :key="idx"> 
    <img @click="changePicture(idx)" class="image" :src="images[idx]?.img" alt="image" width="100px">
    {{ images[idx]?.text }}
  </div>
  {{images}}
</div>
```

Comment: This works as intended! Can you explain it a little bit though? Love to see that you created an empty array and pushed into it, I wouldn't have thought of that!

Comment: Could have also used a `.map` and again, don't use the index for a `key`.